# Sanitize data in Mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have a products mysql table. There is some bad data in the products_image column. Going forward, I can use php and do a str_replace, but my problem is, the current data.

I want to update products_image  which is a url or path to a product image. It has ./ in the path where it should be /.

Is there a way to run an update statement using a stored procedure in mysql (no php) OR, use php as I have done below, but doesn't work well.
When I tried it in php, ( see below ) it worked for the most part but it timed out. (12779 rows ) Hope you can help. Thanks. KP

```
<pre> $sql ="Select products_image from products";
       $result = mysql_query( $sql,$link );
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $products_image = $row['products_image'];
        $image = str_replace("./","/", $products_image);

         $sql1="UPDATE products set products_image='$image'";
         $result1 = mysql_query($sql1,$link);
           }
</pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the REPLACE function.

```
UPDATE products SET products_image = REPLACE(products_image, "./", "/")
```

Answer (score 0):

minimum change to your code is :

change

```
$sql1="UPDATE products set products_image='$image'";
```

to

```
$sql1="UPDATE products set products_image='$image' WHERE products_image = $row['products_image']";
```

Comment: It based on OP codes . it updates `product_image` based on previous `SELECT` statement.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to help with the question.  You would do best to explain your answer a little bit in future.

Comment: Thank you gentlemen. Timothy's answer worked great. It ran in less than a second and did the job. That is what I was looking for. Easy clean where it can run directly in phpmyadmin. To me, this was the answer. For the second answer, I needed to add single quotes around $row['products_image'] but mostly, it timed out as well. I thank you both for answering but the REPLACE function is just what I needed. Many thanks Kip